# "OR" condition in db_select()

Tags: 7, database

I am studying the new database layer, and I am glad it is changed to an OOP layer. I need to implement a query with `db_select()`. I found I can add a `WHERE` statement with `$query->condition()`, but by default the conditions are AND'ed together.

How can I OR the conditions together?

```
$query=db_select('users','u')->fields('u',array('uid','title','created','uid'));
$query->join('flag_content','fc' , 'u.uid = fc.content_id');
$query->condition('fc.fid', '5' , '=');
$query->condition('fc.uid', $uid , '=');
//…
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to drupal 7 [Database documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_select/7)
the default is ***AND*** condition, but if you want to use ***OR*** condition then use this;

```
$db_or = db_or();
$db_or->condition('n.type', 'event', '=');
$db_or->condition('n.type', 'article', '=');
$query->condition($db_or);
```

Answer (score 86):

That's not correct, the default is AND. To use or, you need to use:

```
$or = db_or();
$or->condition();
$or->condition();
$query->condition($or);
```

But the main conditions on the query are definitely joined with AND.

Answer (score 31):

You can use this For making OR between 2 conditions ByDefault it is AND

```
$query=db_select('users','u')->fields('u',array('uid','title','created','uid'));
$query->join('flag_content','fc' , 'u.uid = fc.content_id');

$db_or = db_or();
$db_or->condition('fc.fid', '5' , '=');
$db_or->condition('fc.uid', $uid , '=');
$query->condition($db_or);

$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

It is possible to have AND condition within OR suppose you have 3 conditions and if you want it to be like con1 AND con2 OR con3 and even many other cases in this case you can use db_and like db_or because when you are trying to use db_or all the conditions within db_or takes now in case you want and between those you can use db_and that is little tedious but its possible to implement it. Here is the example below

```
 $query = db_select('work_details_table','wd');
$query->join('work_table','w','wd.request_id = w.request_id');
$query->fields('w',array('client_id'));
$query->fields('wd');
$query->condition('wd.request_id',$request_id);
if($status == 5 || $status == 6 || $status == 7){
  $query->condition('wd.status',$status);
}elseif($user_type == 'writer'){
  $query->condition('wd.writer_id',$user_id);  
  $db_or = db_or();
  $db_and = db_and();
    $db_and->condition('wd.status',2);
    $db_and->isNull('wd.editor_id');
  $db_or->condition('wd.status',4);
  $db_or->condition('wd.status',1);
  $db_or->condition($db_and);
  $query->condition($db_or);
}else if($user_type == 'editor'){
  $query->condition('wd.editor_id',$user_id);
  $db_or = db_or();
  $db_and = db_and();
    $db_and->condition('wd.status',2);
    $db_and->isNotNull('wd.editor_id');
  $db_or->condition('wd.status',3);
  $db_or->condition($db_and);
  $query->condition($db_or); 
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$completed_sku = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

This will give you an idea how the complex and or condition can be handled in Drupal PDO queries .

Answer (score 11):

Simple example:

```
$nodes = db_select('node', 'n')
->fields('n')
->condition(
 db_or()
   ->condition('uid', 1)
   ->condition('status', 0)
 )
->execute()
->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

By default there is AND condition, for OR condition need to add db_or() inside the condition.

```
$query = db_select('soccer_team"', 'n');
$query->fields('n',array('stid','title'))//SELECT the fields from node
        ->fields('n',array('title'))//SELECT the fields from user
            ->condition(
             db_or()
            ->condition('title','%ace%','LIKE')
            ->condition('title','%alb%','LIKE')
            )
        ->orderBy('title', 'ASC');
```

Answer (score 0):

The db_or() solution won't work when you are building a complex query where you want most of the conditions to be conjoined with AND's and just one or some OR condition(s).

I ran into a case like this where I had conditions already, and I didn't want them to be OR conditions. I was able to use the **where() method** instead of condition to add another clause that included an OR. Here's an example similar to the query I used with the where method there near the end:

```
$query = db_select('users');
$query->join('user_join', NULL, 'users.uid = userid');
$query->join('field_data_account', NULL, 'appid = entity_id');
$query->leftJoin('users_roles', 'roles', 'users.uid = roles.uid');
$query->condition('account_target_id', $form['#account_id']);
$query->condition('userid', $lab_user->uid);
$query->where('appid <> :app_id OR rid = :rid', array(
    ':app_id' => $form['#app_id'],
    ':rid' => $role->rid,
))->fields('users')->countQuery();
$result = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

Comment: This answer is not correct: `db_or()` works also when there are just two conditions that need to OR'ed out of 5 conditions that are AND'ed. There is not need to use `$query->where()`, for such case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, how would it be used in that case then? db_select()->condition()->condition()->db_or()->condition()
??

Comment: You need to use something similar to `db_select()->condition($a)->condition($b)->condition(db_or()->condition($c)->condition($d))->condition($e)`; the resulting condition would be `$a AND $b AND ($c OR $d) AND $e`. I am using pseudo-code. `db_or()` is a function, not a method; `db_select()->condition()->db_or()` would return an error about a method not defined.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks again for the explanation. I was under the impression that it was a method. So it would also have worked for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8 you can use e.g.:

```
// Use only records with ACCEPTED or REJECTED action.
$orCondition = $query->orConditionGroup();
$orCondition->condition('action', 'ACCEPTED');
$orCondition->condition('action', 'REJECTED');
$query->condition($orCondition);
```

Answer (score 0):

db_or() is deprecated for Drupal 9: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21database.inc/function/db_or/8.8.x

Following the deprecation notice, this code should be used:

```
use Drupal\Core\Database\Query\Condition;

$or = new Condition('OR');
$or->condition();
$or->condition();
$query->condition($or);
```