# Adding a 'OR' condition to query

Tags: 8, database

I need to add a OR condition to my query so that I can get all nodes related to a particular term. Here is what I have done :

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_index', 'ti');
$query->fields('ti', ['nid']);

// OR CONDITION
$or_group = $query->orConditionGroup()->condition('ti.tid', $params[1], 'IN');

$query->condition('ti.tid', $params[0], 'IN');
$query->condition('ti.status', 1);

// Added OR CONDITION TO QUERY.
$query->condition($or_group);

$query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
```

This is the how the query get build :

> ### QUERY
>
> SELECT ti.nid AS nid
>
> FROM {taxonomy_index} ti
>
> WHERE (ti.tid IN (:db_condition_placeholder_0))
>
> AND (ti.status = :db_condition_placeholder_1)
>
> AND (ti.tid IN (:db_condition_placeholder_2));
>
> ### PARAMS
>
> Array (
>
> [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 170
>
> [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1
>
> [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 227
>
> );

As you can see the last "AND" condition should be "OR".

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“OR” condition in db_select()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/or-condition-in-db-select)

Comment: @NoSssweat , I have implemented the same thing as mentioned in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/32771/66332 but somehow it adding the "AND" condition instead of "OR".

Comment: You’ve only added one condition to the OR group, so it’s still essentially an AND. Add all OR conditions for that group to that group, not as subsequent ANDs

Comment: @Clive, thanks for clearing the doubt. I assumed that `orConditionGroup` adds a 'OR' conditon to the query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["OR" condition in db\_select()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32768/or-condition-in-db-select)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use an or then it should be

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('taxonomy_index', 'ti');
$query->fields('ti', ['nid']);

// OR CONDITION
$or_group = $query->orConditionGroup()
  ->condition('ti.tid', $params[1], 'IN')
  ->condition('ti.tid', $params[0], 'IN');

$query->condition('ti.status', 1);

// Added OR CONDITION TO QUERY.
$query->condition($or_group);

$query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution seemed to be putting the explicit "IN" in the query, making the simplified version:

```
$entity_ids = $query
    ->condition('attributes.color', array('red', 'green'), 'IN')
    ->condition('attributes.building_type', 'bikeshed')
    ->execute();
```